# How to build unit tests for ContinueWith

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

a have this code:

```
var response = await await _service.GetProfile(code)
                                   .ContinueWith(async task =>{
   if(task.IsFaulted)
   {
      ///... anyway
     return object;
   }
});
```

I can't get to IsFault in my unit test.
Can you help me build this unit test?
I'm using Xunit and NSubstitute

Comment: Don't use `ContinueWith` at all; use `await` instead.

Comment: Use await _service.GetProfile(code) for unit testing

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether the code you show is the test or the code you want to write a test for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ContinueWith`. Just use `await`. A faulted `Task` will throw an exception on `await` that you can `catch` and handle.

```
try 
{
  var response = await _service.GetProfile(code);
  
  // Here Task is complete without an exception
}  
catch(Exception ex) 
{
   // Task has faulted
   return object;
}
```

Note that your test method has to be marked `async`.

---

In order to write unit tests for asynchronous code without using await, use synchronization objects like a `ManualResetEvent`.

See my answer here: ["Thread was being aborted." in test that tests code that fires a delegate on a background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495063/thread-was-being-aborted-in-test-that-tests-code-that-fires-a-delegate-on-a-b)